# How to avoid Gradle wrapper downloading distro when running in Gradle docker image?

Tags: gradle, gitlab-ci

My project is built with `gradlew`. GitLab CI builds the project in a docker runner with an official Gradle image (see https://hub.docker.com/_/gradle).

Now even though Gradle is already installed in the cointainer, the wrapper will still download the distro every time. This makes up the majority of the build time.

How can I "tell" the wrapper about the already installed distro, so that it will not redownload it (assuming of course the versions match)?

Of course the alternative is to use `gradle` instead of `gradlew` in CI and rely on the docker image to have the correct distro but I'd like to avoid this if possible, as I would then have to manually keep `.gitlab-ci.yml` and the wrapper config in sync.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you cant instruct the wrapper to use a local version of Gradle that was installed manually.

The only approach I can think of to prevent downloading the distribution on every build, that doesn't involve additional steps when upgrading Gradle, is to cache the Gradle home folder (e.g. /home/gradle/.gradle). This should be possible even if it resides in a Docker container.

I don't know the details of how GitLab supports caching, but it probably only makes sense if the cache is stored locally (either on the same machine or in a cache server with high network bandwidth). If it has to be uploaded and downloaded from something like an S3 bucket on every build, that would likely take as much time as downloading it from services.gradle.org. But if you can make this work, you will not only cache the Gradle distribution but also the build dependencies, which should further speed up the build.

Comment: I also had this idea but found the [GitLab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#cache) state "You can only [cache] paths that are within the project workspace." Not sure if this includes the user home dir or not. I tried setting `GRADLE_USER_HOME` to `./.gradle` but for some reason, this caused `gradlew` to get stuck on downloading the distro. Still not sure why - have to investigate further.

Comment: Oh and depending on where the docker volumes are located physically, I'd expect that caching could still improve performance, e.g. if they are in the same datacenter as the cache.

Comment: There is already a ./.gradle folder with different content, but you can set it to pretty much anything else like ./.gradle_home.

Comment: I ended up following [this](https://gist.github.com/daicham/5ac8461b8b49385244aa0977638c3420) example. I had tried it using GitLab's variables which didn't work. Using `export` as in the example seems to do the trick.

Comment: lol, I just realized you are this guy: https://github.com/bjornvester/xjc-gradle-plugin/issues/3#issuecomment-535460994
Small World...

Comment: Haha, indeed it is :)